# How to get an attribute of an object that is stored in array list of array lists?

Tags: java, arraylist, anylogic

I have an arrayList LAL that is filled with other arraylists via add function, like that:

```
for(int i=0;i<v_amountComponentOptions;i++){
    ArrayList AL=new ArrayList<CustomerOrder>();
    LAL.add(AL);
}
```

Then I add orders (orders have the attribute product and quantity) to this List of Array List, like that:

```
LAL.get(0).add(order);
```

When I try to plot the quantity as follows, I get an error. It says that there is no quantity value.

```
traceln(LAL.get(0).get(0).quantity);
```

However, when I write;

```
traceln(LAL.get(0).get(0).quantity);
```

Then, the output is :

```
root( product = 1, quantity = 63 )
```

My point is that I need to get the quantity value. Could anyone tell me how to do that? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: The two statement behaving differently look the same.  Also what does your class look like?  Do you have getters and setters?  Are the fields accessible?

Comment: Post your CustomerOrder class. It looks like quantity either doesn't exist on CustomerOrder or is private.

Answer (score 1):

One possiblity is to use a stream and put all the quantity values in a List.  Assuming the quantities are `Integers` and the quantity value is accessible you could do something like this.

```
List<Integer> list = LAL.stream()
                 .flatMap(List::stream)
                 .map(a->a.quantity)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And if you had getters, this would be even better.

```
List<Integer> list = LAL.stream()
                 .flatMap(List::stream)
                 .map(CustomerOrder::getQuantity)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```